# LazyColumn item not updated accordingly while list in room table already updated

Tags: android-room, android-jetpack-compose

When the `Icon` clicked, `viewModel.onLockIconClicked(it)` is called to reverse the value of `isLock` in db.

The `Icon` is expected to be updated according based on the value of `isLock`.

I've checked the value did reversed in db table. But LazyColumn not update accordingly.

What did I miss? Thanks a lot!

Ex, initially, `Screen: icon = lock` and `Db: isLock = true`,

when `Icon` clicked, `Screen: icon = lock` and `Db: isLock = false`,

while expected is `Screen: icon = lock_open` and `Db: isLock = false`.

`ListScreen`:

```
@Composable
fun ListScreen(context: Context) {
    val viewModel: ListViewModel =
        viewModel(factory = ListViewModelFactory(Db.getInstance(context)))

    val list by viewModel.list.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())

    Scaffold() {
        SwipeRefresh(
            state = rememberSwipeRefreshState(viewModel.isRefreshing),
            onRefresh = { }
        ) {
            LazyColumn(
                state = rememberLazyListState(),
            ) {
                items(list) {
                    Row() {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(if (it.isLock) R.drawable.ic_baseline_lock_24 else R.drawable.ic_baseline_lock_open_24),
                            contentDescription = null,
                            modifier = Modifier.clickable() { viewModel.onLockIconClicked(it) }
                        )

                        Text(it.code)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ListViewModel`:

```
class ListViewModel(db: Db) : ViewModel() {
    private val sumDao = db.sumDao()
    val list = sumDao.getAllRows()

    var isRefreshing by mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

    //init
    init {

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val initialCodeList = listOf("aaa", "bbb")

            for (code in initialCodeList) {
                val sum = Sum()
                sum.code = code
                sumDao.insert(sum)
            }
        }
    }

    fun onLockIconClicked(sum: Sum) {
        sum.isLock = !sum.isLock

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            sumDao.update(sum)
        }

    }

}

class ListViewModelFactory(private val db: Db) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(ListViewModel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return ListViewModel(db) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

`Sum`:

```
@Entity(tableName = "sum", primaryKeys = ["code"])
data class Sum(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "code")
    var code: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_lock")
    var isLock: Boolean = true
)
```

`SumDao`:

```
@Dao
interface SumDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(sum: Sum): Long

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun update(sum: Sum): Int

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(sum: Sum): Int

    @Query("select * from sum")
    fun getAllRows(): Flow<List<Sum>>
}
```

`Db`:

```
@Database(entities = [Sum::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class Db : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun sumDao(): SumDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: Db? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): Db {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    Db::class.java,
                    "db"
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()

                INSTANCE = instance

                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider taking the [State-in-Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state) for a better understanding of the concepts of state-handling in Compose.

I'm sorry but the information that you have provided is massive, so I can't pinpoint the source of the bug, but here's what you can do for now:

In your `Dao` class, just replace the words `Flow<List<Sum>>` with `LiveData<List<Sum>>`

In your `ViewModel`, you can get access to the `LiveData` inside the `init` like so

```
var list by mutableStateListOf<Sum>()

init{
  sumDao.getAllRows().observeForever{
    list = it
  }
}
```

Now, `list` would ideally be updated every time the value in the databse changes, which infact would trigger recompositions since I am using a direct `mutableStateListOf` object here.

The problem may lie anywhere:

Since the class `Sum` is a custom-made class, it may have been experiencing issues triggering recompositions, which is a common problem among new developers, and even some experienced ones nowadays.

Since you are declaring the viewModel inside the Composable, wrong instances of ViewModels may have been passed around, leading to state-inconsistency - always try to declare your viewModels in the top-most layer possibly, i.e., somewhere like the `onCreate` method of the activity. Fragments are discourages so you should not face any problems over there.

Since you were not actively observing the Flow anywhere, that could have lead to the variable not being updated at all in the `ViewModel`, which would again lead to UI-inconsistency.